# Using Model in join() method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is there a way to use Model name in `join()` as a parameter instead of table name.

Ex. database Table name is **'SeriesGenres'**, but Model name **'SerieGenre'**.

```php
public function showContent($id){
        $serie = Serie::findOrFail($id);

        // SELECT Genres.name
        // FROM Genres INNER JOIN SeriesGenres ON Genres.id = SeriesGenres.Genre_id
        // WHERE SeriesGenres.Serie_id = $serie

        $getGenreNamesById = Genre::select('name')
                   ->join('SeriesGenres', 'SeriesGenres.Genre_id', '=', 'Genres.id')
                   ->whereIn('Serie_id',$serie)->get();
}
```

Want to do something like this:

```php
$serieGenre =SerieGenre::all();
$getGenreNamesById = Genre::select('name')
                   ->join($serieGenre, 'Genre_id', '=', 'Genres.id')
                   ->whereIn('Serie_id',$serie)->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is using QueryBuilder instead of Eloquent. In your `Serie` model file, you should define a function to access the `Genre` relationship.

From what I understand from your code, You've got a Many-to-Many relationship between Genre and Serie.

I'm assuming the primary keys for `Serie` and `Genre` are both named `id` and the foreign keys in `SerieGenre` are named `Genre_id` and `Serie_id` respectively based on your code

```
// App\Serie.php

public function series_genres()
{
    // hasMany($related, $foreign_key, $local key)
    // if you don't specify the $foreign_key, Laravel will assume it's named 'serie_id' based on its conventions.
    // if you don't specify the $local_key, Laravel will assume it's named 'id' which is the case so we don't need to specify
    return $this->hasMany('App\SerieGenre', 'Serie_id');
}

public function genres()
{
    // belongsToMany($related, $table, $foreignPivotKey, $relatedPivotKey, $parentKey, $relatedKey, $relation)
    // if you don't specify the $table, Laravel will assume it's named 'serie_genre' based on its conventions.
    // if you don't specify the $foreignPivotKey, Laravel will assume it's named 'serie_id' based on its conventions.
    // if you don't specify the $relatedPivotKey, Laravel will assume it's named 'genre_id' based on its conventions.
    // if you don't specify the $parentKey, Laravel will assume it's named 'id' which is the case so we don't need to specify
    // if you don't specify the $local_key, Laravel will assume it's named 'id' which is the case so we don't need to specify
    // You don't need to worry about the $related variable
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\SerieGenre','SeriesGenres', 'Serie_id', 'Genre_id');
}
```

If you want to access the Serie or the Genre model from the pivot table, you should define the following functions as well.

```
// App\SerieGenre.php

public function serie()
{
    // belongsTo($related, $foreignKey, $ownerKey, $relation)
    // if you don't specify the $foreign_key, Laravel will assume it's named 'serie_id' based on its conventions.
    // if you don't specify the $local_key, Laravel will assume it's named 'id' which is the case so we don't need to specify
    // you don't need to worry about the $relation variable
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Serie', 'Serie_id');
}

public function genre()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Genre', 'Genre_id');
}
```

And finally, if you want to access the Serie relationship from the Genre model, it's the same thing.

```
// App\Genre.php

public function series_genres()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\SerieGenre', 'Genre_id');
}

public function series()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\SerieGenre','SeriesGenres', 'Genre_id', 'Serie_id');
}
```

Usually you do not need to pass more than one parameter to the relationship functions but that's true only if you follow laravel's way of writing things (singular StudlyCase for Models, plural snake_case for table names, id as primary key and snake_case'd model name +_id for foreign keys)

Finally, you need to ask yourself if you want only the relationship's detail or if you also need the model itself.

In this example, the Serie with id=2 is related to Genre with id=4 (among others)
`Serie::find(2)->genres()` will produce the following object

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {
    all: [
        App\Genre {
            id: 4,
            name: 'name',
            ...,
            pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {
                Genre_id: 4,
                Serie_id: 2,
                ...,
            },
        },
        App\Genre {...},
        App\Genre {...},
    ],
}
```

`Serie::with('genres')->find(2)` will produce the following object

```
App\Serie {
    id: 2,
    Genres: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {
        all: [
            App\Genre {
                id: 4,
                name: 'name'
                ...,
                pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {
                    Genre_id: 4,
                    Serie_id: 2,
                    ...,
                },
            },
            App\Genre {...},
            App\Genre {...},
            App\Genre {...},
            App\Genre {...},
    ],
},
```

I suggest you read the documentation because this topic is better explained there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try accessing the table name like this:

```
(new SerieGenre)->getTable();
```

It'll return the table's name.

So it'll be like:

```
$serieGenre =SerieGenre::all();
$getGenreNamesById = Genre::select('name')
                   ->join((new SerieGenre)->getTable(), 'Genre_id', '=', 'Genres.id')
                   ->whereIn('Serie_id',$serie)->get();
```